# vba ".find" stopped working

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word, ms-access-2007

Currently this code runs with no error message but does not make the requested replacement:

```vb
Private Sub TestingButton_Click()

    Dim RngFound As Range
    Dim FileToProcess As Word.Document
    Dim WordInstance As Object

    Set WordInstance = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'For these tests I close Word first.
    Set FileToProcess = WordInstance.Documents.Open("c:\sarah\junk\Attach.doc")
    WordInstance.ActiveDocument.Range.Select 'Gets the whole document
    Toolbox.SetupFind (WordInstance.ActiveDocument.Range)
    With WordInstance.ActiveDocument.Range.Find
        .Text = "rock"
        .Replacement.Text = "found it!"
        .Execute
    End With

End Sub
```

In the Toolbox module:

```vb
 Public Function SetupFind(ByRef RngPassed As Word.Range)

   With RngPassed.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = ""
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = False
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
      .Execute
    End With

End Function
```

The code above is from a test database that I created for troubleshooting.  My destination is an Access form whose purpose is to extract some information from a set of documents, and place the information in a database.  It was working fine.  It stopped working after a particularly spectacular crash.  I tried to remove a label while the form was in break mode.  (I know,... deep regret)  I couldn't close Access even with ctrl-break.  Probably the wierdest part is that similar code now no longer works in back-up copies of the database either.

> Here are things I've tried that haven't worked:

Re-import all objects into a new database.Similarly, rebuild the backend database. Break the form's code (a couple thousand lines)
 into modules. Copy all the code into Notepad, save it, then create a
    button in a new empty database.  Recreate subs & functions by
    typing, then once they exist, paste in the code from Wordpad. Reset
    the form's references, which include MSWord. Make a brand new form
    in the new database with one button that has only the displayed
    code. Use a defined range:  This all started when I got a persistent
    error in RngToSearch.find.execute findtext:="reason".  The error
    highlighted .find and said 'Argument not optional.'  So among other
    things, I switched to a selection rather than a defined range in my
    attempts to isolate the problem.  But working with a range rather
    than a selection is where I really need to end up again.

> Possibly relevant observations:

Other forms in the same database with lots of backend code work fine.  So do other routines in the same form.
Only one document is open.  As far as I can tell, there's nothing unusual about the document. I have tried multiple documents.
The text to find exists in the document, outside of a table.

Things that have worked, as they might be clues:
In Word straight up, no code, no nothing, use 'find' to select the targeted word.
WordInstance.ActiveDocument.Range.Text = Replace(WordInstance.ActiveDocument.Range.Text, "rock", "Found it!").  Trouble is, what I ultimately need to do again is way more complex than Replace can handle.

Comment: That works!  THANK you

Comment: ... and it turns out the underlying problem was that in recreating databases over the weeks, I'd got sloppy with precedence of references.  Since Excel comes before Word alphabetically and both are referenced in the form's code, my range was trying to be an excel.range and therefore wasn't populating.  Specifying it thus worked:  dim RngFound as word.range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the scope for the replacement(s).  The code worked for me from Access 2010 with this change in `TestingButton_Click()` ...

```vb
'.Execute
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

`Toolbox.SetupFind` also calls `.Execute`.  Since the find and replacement text are both empty strings at that point and no scope is specified, `.Execute` doesn't cause harm ... but it doesn't seem useful either.

Comment: ^^ The boss. -- In addition: the line `WordInstance.ActiveDocument.Range.Select` is unnecessary, because you aren't working on `Selection`, but on a range. @InColorado